# Why is my camcorder creating 10:40 clips?

Tags: camcorder, sd-card, sony

I was given a used Sony NEX VG20 as a gift.  I bought this SD card for it - "SanDisk 128GB Extreme SDXC UHS-I Card - C10, U3, V30, 4K UHD, SD Card - SDSDXV5-128G-GNCIN", [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07H48412Q/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07H48412Q).

I tried filming with it today for just over 50 minutes straight and it produced five files - four at 10 minutes, 40 seconds and one at 9 minutes, 25 seconds.  While this is OK, for the most part, the problem is, when it ends one file and creates the new one, it doesn't capture the audio for that split second.

I was unable to find a setting anywhere on the camcorder to increase or decrease the maximum length of a single clip.

Is there a way for me to set this camcorder to capture everything as one file?

I also wondered if this is a limitation of the SD card I'm using.  Do SD cards have a limitation on the size of a single file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most devices use memory formatted as FAT32, which gives you a 4GB file size limit, so a recording is broken up across multiple files. For Sony products, Catalyst Browse is normally the software used to re-combine the files:
https://www.sonycreativesoftware.com/catalystbrowse

Normally you would import the files off the card using that, then select the files together and right click/combine. It should make a continuous single file recording from the source files, with nothing missing.

Comment: Thank you, Peter.  I am downloading Catalyst Browse now and will give it a try.

Comment: Thank you again, Peter.  Using Catalyst Browser, I was able to access the multiple clips as a single linked *.m2ts file and copy them from my SD card to my computer.  I did some quick testing and this single file does not seem to have the audio gaps either.

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear that this was able to fix the file up for you.